# Can't run html on text string in JQuery tmpl

Tags: jquery, jquery-templates

In a JQuery template in my project, I am trying to write out a variable which is an HTML string without encoding the HTML.  When I just output the variable like so:

```
 ${description}
```

it results in the raw HTML string being outputted with tags and all like so:

```
<p>text <b>bold</b>  <i>italic</i></p>
```

But when I try to turn the markup into real tags at the same exact place in the code:

```
   {{html $description}}
```

doesn't output anything!

I tried a zillion ways of passing in the variable, but I think there's something going on in the html routine I'm not getting.

Thanks.

**Update:**

Here's how it's being called:

```
    this.$el.attr('data-id', tmplData.id).
          data('id', tmplData.id).html($.tmpl(this.template, tmplData));
```

Where this.template is the template file and tmplData is JSON which includes $description and the other variables needed.

**Another update:**

```
 {{html '<p>string</p>'}}
```

does behave as expected.  But

```
 {{html $another_variable}}
```

fails to produce any output even when $another_variable doesn't have an HTML in it.

**Another update:**

I also tried:

```
 ${$item.html(description)}
```

and changed the call to the template to

```
 this.$el.attr('data-id', tmplData.id).
         data('id', tmplData.id).
         html($.tmpl(this.template, tmplData, {
            truncate: _.truncateStrip,
            html: _.html,
        }));
```

And wrote a custom html routine to pass through the string unchanged as was recommended:

```
 html: function(str) {
        return str;
    }
```

but still no dice.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The answer is:

```
{{html description}}
```

I tried that early on, but because I left stray spaces inside the curly brackets, it did not interpret properly.

:-(

Comment: Thanks, mine didn't work at first, because I still had the dollar sign in front.

Comment: That's the best and most proper answer by far, far, far. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

If you open the source you can modify the line that does the encoding.  I didn't see an option to turn it off so this might be the easiest solution for you.

Change:

```
encode: function( text ) {
            // Do HTML encoding replacing < > & and ' and " by corresponding entities.
            return ("" + text).split("<").join("&lt;").split(">").join("&gt;").split('"').join("&#34;").split("'").join("&#39;");
        }
```

to

```
encode: function( text ) {
            // Do HTML encoding replacing < > & and ' and " by corresponding entities.
            return text;        
}
```

Comment: I didn't want to make a global change, but see the last edit above -- I tried something like what you recommended,  but it made no difference.